# JSON Response Parsing in Android?

Tags: android, json

Hi i'm trying to do some wordbook project for Android and i got some issues with it application should be like this;

1-First when application starts it must send some data to server and parse it's response as a json data

e.g http://sozluk.smilens.com/token/?uygulamaadi=sozlukAndroid but it turns just a id number and i can't

find any parsing example such as this one if I handle this issue next i need to save this id data to

disk( to Android Device I dont know how :) )  and use some gcm push notifications etc :) but first i

need to solve this can someone help me? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject mObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
int mId = mObject.getInt("id"); //62351
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot open that link provided in your question, so i am providing one example, hope this helps you.

JSon Response string:

```
{
"data": [
{
  "param1": "dfdfg",
  "param2": "dfgdfgd",
  "param3": "dfgdfert"
},
{
  "param1": "werwer",
  "param2": "4re345",
  "param3": "ertrtr"
},
{
  "param1": "nmnmn",
  "param2": "nmbjhg",
  "param3": "bjhkjknm"
}
]
}
```

Parsing:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(your_response_string);

String arr = jsonObject.getString("data");
                JSONArray jsonPhneArray = new JSONArray(arr);

                if (jsonPhneArray.length() > 0) {

                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonPhneArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jObj = jsonPhneArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String str1 = jObj.getString("param1");
                        String str2 = jObj.getString("param2");
                        String str3 = jObj.getString("param3");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: thanks but data that I mentioned in quest didnt have form like array it just a {"id":62692} like this :D

Comment: then you can simply use                                     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(your_response_string);
int val = jsonObject.getInt("id");